# I have the following bug in react native paper library

Tags: react-native

I have the following bug in react native paper library:

> Unable to resolve module `./components/TextInput` my react-native-paper version is 2.16.0

Comment: I think you need to post code in component have issue. Now still lack info to know what's issue.

Comment: can you share your `import` statements for the affected file?

Comment: import { Text, Divider } from 'react-native-paper';

Comment: @harish where is the part on the above `./components/TextInput/`? if you can find it, comment it and run your app again.